# Save NppFTP information in NPP Portable?

Tags: notepad++, portable-apps

I am using NPP Portable for a while to have always my NppFTP information with me.
But last time, all gets broken.

So my question ist: how to backup all FTP connections in NPP Portable?

I've noticed if NPP runs, it creates a DIR in

`<USB-Drive>:\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\App\Notepad++\plugins\config`

if closed the "config"-DIR is gone. So normally the stored information should go into

`<USB-Drive>:\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\App\Notepad++\plugins\config\NppFTP\NppFTP.xml`

but ain't.

Any help/ information would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: SynWrite app uses also clone of NppFTP: SynFTP, so it creates file SynFTP.xml in same format, in portable dir. It must not erase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not catch this "SynFTP" - how to use it? Hava link - tutorial - oder something ? Thank you.

Comment: U just install Synwrite. It's with SynFTP plugin. In Synwrite just press btn "FTP" in left panel, near "Tree". And ftp shown

Comment: Allright, got it. Would be nice, to hava easier way - but can life with it for now. Thank you.